# Angular ng-if to determine input number value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Quite simple just not too sure how to code it, I have an input box which sets a value, it then submits the value for processing, Currently I want the value to default to 0 in the input box, if it is currently not assigned a value, i.e 10.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <label for="totalStaff" style="padding-bottom: 10px; width: 150px;">Number of Staff</label>
    <button class="form-button" ng-click="staff.staffTotal = staff.staffTotal - 1" ng-disabled="staff.staffTotal === 0">-</button>
    <input class="form-control max-width" type="number" id="totalStaff" name="totalStaff" min="0"
    ng-model="staff.staffTotal" 
    ng-blur="myform.totalStaff.$touched=true" 
    ng-required="true" 
    ng-class="{'input-error': myform.totalStaff.$touched && myform.totalStaff.$error.required}"
    ng-if="isEmpty"  
    />
    <button class="form-button" ng-click="staff.staffTotal = staff.staffTotal + 1">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller isEmpty function

```
    $scope.isEmpty = function(number) {         
        return (number == undefined || number == null || number == "");
    };
```

So at this stage it does everything but either assign the value of 0, or the value by the user. I want the values to default to 0, as  they are not all mandatory, but the form won't allow submissions with empty input fields.

Comment: Why can't you just assign the model a default value of 0?

Answer (score 1):

in the initialization of scope, set staff.staffTotal to be 0.
i.e.

```
$scope.staff.staffTotal = 0;
$scope.isEmpty = function() {
  return $scope.staff.staffTotal == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Angular way would be that you initialize staff.staffTotal as 0 somewhere in your controller.

Otherwise I'd just go with adding value="0"